# in mac I keep getting -bash: ls-a: command not found ? How to fix this?

Tags: shell, terminal, command-line

I am taking a class and I need to use the commands such as ls-a in teriminal on mac and everytime I type a command it says -bash: ls-a: command not found. How do I fix this I am lost and a beginner?

I honestly don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: someone answered my question it was a typo on my end. Their should be a use white space after the command "ls".

Answer (score 0):

You should use white space after the command "ls". There is no command called "ls-a".

"ls" is the actual command with the flag "-a" (which should be seperated using a space) which lists all files including hidden ones.

Just try

```
ls -a
```

and you should be all good.